# Flatten out cell value that is a range into columns

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I have a table that has a column for page ranges of documents, and want to expand the table so that each page in the range is its own row.

I have:

```
| document | type | page_range |
| -------- | ---- | ---------- |
|        1 |  A   |    1-3     |
|        2 |  B   |    4-5     |
```

I want:

```
| document | type | pages |
| -------- | ---- | ----- |
|        1 |  A   |   1   |
|        1 |  A   |   2   |
|        1 |  A   |   3   |
|        2 |  B   |   4   |
|        2 |  B   |   5   |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can

- extract range bounds using [`regexp_extract`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#regexp_extract)
- convert range bounds to value list using [`sequence`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#sequence)
- flatten using `CROSS JOIN UNNEST`

Like this:

```
SELECT id, x
FROM (VALUES ('A', '1-3'), ('B', '4-5')) t(id, range)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST (
    sequence(
        CAST(regexp_extract(range, '(\d+)-(\d+)', 1) AS bigint),
        CAST(regexp_extract(range, '(\d+)-(\d+)', 2) AS bigint))
) s(x);
```

Example output:

```
presto> SELECT id, x
     -> FROM (VALUES ('A', '1-3'), ('B', '4-5')) t(id, range)
     -> CROSS JOIN UNNEST (
     ->     sequence(
     ->         CAST(regexp_extract(range, '(\d+)-(\d+)', 1) AS bigint),
     ->         CAST(regexp_extract(range, '(\d+)-(\d+)', 2) AS bigint))
     -> ) s(x);
 id | x
----+---
 A  | 1
 A  | 2
 A  | 3
 B  | 4
 B  | 5
(5 rows)
```